# C# Reindent code tool

Tags: c#, code-formatting

I'm looking for a tool that will rearrange some C# code and reindent it (more or less like the "Format Document" will do in Visual Studio).

All the tools I've found so far (Narrange, Regionerate) are very good but they do not reindent the code.

The tool I need must be called from the command line.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Artistic Style](http://sourceforge.net/projects/astyle/) can be called [from command line](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/astyle.html#_Command_Line_Only).

Answer (score 2):

http://www.sourceformat.com/feature.htm

http://astyle.sourceforge.net/

http://sourceforge.net/projects/uncrustify/

Answer (score 0):

See our [C# Formatter](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Formatters/CppFormatter.html).